# Doxygen build failing with undefined reference to `libiconv_close', `libiconv', `libiconv_open'

Tags: doxygen

I'm unable to build Doxygen on x86_64-linux.
I have Doxygen-1.8.6 unpacked.
I have libiconv-1.14 unpacked, built, installed.

I keep getting:

```
g++ -c -pipe -fsigned-char -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -W -O2 -I../qtools -I../libmd5 -I. -o ../objects/main.o main.cpp
g++  -o ../bin/doxygen ../objects/main.o  -L../lib -ldoxygen -ldoxycfg -lqtools -lmd5 -lpthread 
../lib/libdoxycfg.a(portable_c.o): In function `portable_iconv_close':
portable_c.c:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `libiconv_close'
../lib/libdoxycfg.a(portable_c.o): In function `portable_iconv':
portable_c.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `libiconv'
../lib/libdoxycfg.a(portable_c.o): In function `portable_iconv_open':
portable_c.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `libiconv_open'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which iconv gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/iconv
```

as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the link line I don't see a reverence to the iconv library. Looks like something is not configured properly. Did you run configure before installing iconv?

Comment: I configured before I build libiconv - I didn't set any particular flags, just ./configure.  I configured the doxygen build - again nothing special.  I didn't see any settings for libiconv anyway.

Comment: I tried it on a RHEL system and there the iconv is coming from glibc (by head version 2.2.5), on cygwin the -liconv is explicitly added to the link line (in the configuration step in src/doxygen.pro.in).

Comment: I'm on RHEL 5.* - this could be an old libiconv.  I know the glibc is pretty old - missing uchar.h etc.  Do you think I could hack something to allow me to provide the link line on RHEL so I can use my new libiconv?  These configury things can be tricky.

Comment: Yes I think you could hack something by adding the library to your link path analogous like it is done for cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

add **-liconv** to the end of the line in *src/doxygen.pro.in*:

```
unix:LIBS                  += -L../lib -ldoxygen -lvhdlparser -ldoxycfg -lqtools -lmd5 -lpthread %%SQLITE3_LIBS%% %%LIBCLANG_LIBS%% -liconv
```